# Как добавить выпадающий список в модальное окно Razor Psges

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Я не понимаю как добавить выпадающий список с имеющимся должностями в модальное окно *( окно используется для добавления нового преподавателя в базу данных)*. Я так понимаю проблема в том, что в методе OnGet, помимо самого выпадающего списка, есть ещё список со всеми преподавателями. На данный момент мой код выглядит вот так:

```
public class EmployeesModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
    private readonly ApplicationdbContext _dbContext;
    [BindProperty]
    public SelectList Posts { get; set; }
    public Employee NewEmployee { get; set; }
    public EmployeesModel(ApplicationdbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void PostDropDownLists(object selectedPost)
    {
        var PostsQuery = from p in _dbContext.Posts
                                         select p;

        Posts = new SelectList(PostsQuery.AsNoTracking(),
            nameof(Post.Id),
            nameof(Post.Name),
            selectedPost);
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Employees = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();
        PostDropDownLists(_dbContext);
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _dbContext.Employees.Add(NewEmployee);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToPage("Employees");

    }
}
```

Ошибка, которая появляется при добавлении:
[image]

Я пробовала писать вот так:

```
public class EmployeesModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
    private readonly ApplicationdbContext _dbContext;
    [BindProperty]
    public List<SelectListItem> Posts { get; set; }
    public Employee NewEmployee { get; set; }
    public EmployeesModel(ApplicationdbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
        
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Employees = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();
        Posts = _dbContext.Posts.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        }).ToList();
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _dbContext.Employees.Add(NewEmployee);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToPage("Employees");

    }
}
```

Но тогда получается NullReferenceException.
Помогите пожалуйста :(

Comment: Вам ведь в ошибке прямым текстом сказано что не так, дословный перевод: `Связанные с моделью
сложные типы не должны быть абстрактными или типами значений и должны иметь конструктор без параметров. Запись должны иметь единственный первичный конструктор. В качестве альтернативы задайте параметру 'Posts' не нулевое значение по умолчанию.` Ну и теперь смотрим на ваш код, видим конструктор с параметрами `public EmployeesModel(ApplicationdbContext dbContext){...}`, не видим "не нулевое значение по умолчанию для `Posts`. Делайте все, что сказано в ошибке, либо удаляйте `[BindProperty]`.